# Store enum class reference

Tags: java, generics, enums, wildcard

Ok i have two enums:

```
    public enum AnotherEnum
    {
        value1, value2, value3;
    }

    public enum MyEnum implements MyInterface
    {
        value1(AnotherEnum);

        generic_reference_type a;

        MyEnum ( ?? )
        {
            a = ??
        }

        GetGenericReference()
        {
            return this.a;
        }
    }
```

I want `MyEnum` to store a reference to the `AnotherEnum` class so I'll be able to do this:

```
    MyEnum.value1.GetGenericReference().values();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: So there's no java trickery to pull this off?

Comment: Just do AnotherEnum.values()

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Well, you could give them state. Even mutable state. Probably not a good idea, but you could...

Comment: I want to be able to use one enum to reference multiple other enums. The actual enum object so I can pull the enum values from each different enum.

Comment: @user2365072 Dynamically, or as a constant? If dynamic use a class. If as a constant, just add a method to return the appropriate "other" enums as a list or array...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch enums in Java can have state.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch See https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/bebdb7f2282667fd1eca

Comment: You can't make two ONEs.  You said "enums don't have state.", and I disagree.  That is unrelated to the idea that you can't create two ONEs.  In the enum I showed, ONE has state and TWO has state.

Comment: The conversation is now difficult to follow because comments from @ElliottFrisch have been deleted.  Apologies to the OP for any confusion.  Enums can in fact have state, and often do.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am not sure what you mean by "Enums cannot have dynamic state", but they can have the same kind of state as a normal class in Java.  You can mutate state, assign new values, change existing values, etc.

Comment: @Jeff so isn't for conversation. Enums have value, not state. For state the value would need to change. That is, it would be a class instance.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "Enums have value, not state. For state the value would need to change. That is, it would be a class instance." An enum value is an instance of the enum class, an enum can have state and that state can change.  You can't create new instances of the enum class but that doesn't appear to be related to what you are saying.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Also, with respect to "For state the value would need to change.", that really isn't the case.  Lots of state doesn't change.  There is mutable state and immutable state.  Enums can have either, both, or neither, but the claim that in order for something to be state it has to change is not correct.

Comment: @Jeff with regards to ops question, this is relevant how? Also, a finite state machine with only one state doesn't seem very useful. Enums are for constants. They have .ordinal() value

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "with regards to ops question, this is relevant how?" it is relevant because he/she is trying to understand the possibilities of enums, you made several erroneous claims about enums (all of which have since been deleted except the original "enums don't have state." which is still there), and I corrected those for the benefit of the person trying to better understand enums.  That is the relevance.

Comment: @elliot Jeff is correct: Enums can have state just like any class. They can have fields that are mutable, setter methods, whatever. The only restriction us that they are all instances of the enum class (which can't sxtend another class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly. you would like to pass a *different* generic type to each instance of an enum... well you can't do that, because every instance of an enum is from the *same* class, which can be generic, but if generic must have the *same* generic parameter.

However, you can get something close to your intention by basing your code around an enum *class*, which is expressed as `Class<? extends Enum<?>>`:

```
public enum AnotherEnum {
    A, B, C;
}

public enum YetAnotherEnum {
    X, Y, Z;
}

public interface MyInterface {
    public Enum<?>[] getGenericReferenceValues();
}

public enum MyEnum implements MyInterface {
    value1(AnotherEnum.class),
    value2(YetAnotherEnum.class);

    final Class<? extends Enum<?>> a;

    private MyEnum(Class<? extends Enum<?>> a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public Enum<?>[] getGenericReferenceValues() {
        return a.getEnumConstants();
    }
}
```

---

And to see it working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(MyEnum.value1.getGenericReferenceValues()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(MyEnum.value2.getGenericReferenceValues()));
}
```

Output:

```
[A, B, C]
[X, Y, Z]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the class, you get get the values of a generic enum with reflections

```
Object someEnum = ...
// get all the values for the same Enum type.
Object[] enums = someEnum.getClass().getEnumConstants()
```

Comment: Thanks but having `object` as an argument to the `MyEnum` constructor doesn't allow me to specify `AnotherEnum` as a parameter. For example: `value1(AnotherEnum)` is not valid.

Comment: @user2365072 If you need it to be a specific type you can cast it.  or better yet, if you know the concrete type, you can get the values() from that type.

Comment: Something like `((Enum<?>)someEnum).getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()` would be better, because `.getClass()` will not get the correct result for enums with class bodies.